# I want to get all my tables with some sort value

Tags: mysql

How can I assign some custom order to each table and retrieve them?

`SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dolceVita'` Generally returns tables by alphabetical order which is not useful for my case.

Comment: What order do you want?

Comment: *Returns tables by alphabetical order.* Not always, only in most cases. The order is indefinite in practice.

Comment: @P.Salmon With a customer order.

So lets say I have tables
`user`
`customer`
`company`

I want to assign an arbitrary number to all the tables defined. Then fetch them according to those arbitrary numbers

Comment: You have not mentioned what ORDER you want. 
Generally if you want your own custom ordering you will need to add some additional columns that calculate your rank ordering and are sorted according to that.

Read MySQL documentation, or any standard SQL documentation. SQL is one language that has vast amounts of high-quality technical documentation on how to use it. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html